# Pandas - read_sql_query filling up column name

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a query using pandas read_sql_query but seems like it is filling up incorrect values. Is there any way I can handle this?

[image]

The column name is 31_to_60_A, and so on. I think my original data is overwritten.

Code:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)

# save as CSV
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: Could you also show us how you're importing the file?

Comment: Also, what the source data? Could you run something like "select * from ..." in your SQL database?

Comment: In order to realize if your SQL query or pandas is problematic, you can run the query in the database CLI and compare it with the results given by pandas, and update your post with the results, if it's not solved

Comment: I think the problem is with `read_sql_query`, as when I download data from hue (database is not on local) and read using `read_csv`, it works fine.